# Quick-Find Union on N Elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm new to algorithms and was hoping someone could explain why the maximum number of id[] array entries that can be changed in one call to union using quick-find is n-1? Preferably in Layman's terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know at least one value isn't changing right?  It's the value that you are adding to the equivalence class of - since the edge-relation is reflexive!  There are n-1 others.

If this isn't obvious, re-read the description of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it: the union-find data structure maintains an array where each index holds the id of that node's "parent" in a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest) (a disjoint union of trees) if it has one, otherwise it holds its own id. A new id is written into the array if and only if the algorithm adds a new edge or changes an existing edge. The maximum number of edges you can have in a forest on *n* nodes is *n* - 1, which occurs in the case that the forest is a tree including every node.